# Using Ajax and Jquery to update other Divs after a div selection

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to update divs after a certain Div is selected.Actually i am querying my results in Laravel(php) and AJAX is requesting.I have tried to update the divs but have not been successful.In this case after the drug is selected it price should automatically be loaded in its div.Have some more to work on but a guide on this could help me.

```
<div  class="form-group {{ $errors->has('drugid') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item Name <span class="highlight-text"> *</span>:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                                                <select  id="drugid" name="drugid"   class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Select Item..">
                                                 <option value="{{old('drugid')}}">{{old('drugid')}}</option>
                                                   <!-- @foreach($drugs as $pdrugz)
                                                <option value="{{$pdrugz->id}}"> {{$pdrugz->drug_name }} - {{$pdrugz->refno }}</option>
                                                  @endforeach -->
                                                  <?php
                                                    DB::table('med_drugs')->where('cur_bal', '>',0)->where('archieved_status','=',null)->orwhere('archieved_status','!=','Yes')->orderBy('id')->chunk(10000, function ($drugs) {
                                                   foreach ($drugs as $pdrugz) {
                                                       ?>
                                                      <option value="{{$pdrugz->id}}"> {{$pdrugz->drug_name }} - {{$pdrugz->bar_code_number }} - [ Stock: {{$pdrugz->cur_bal }} ] - [ Price: {{$pdrugz->current_sp }} ]</option>
                                                   <?php     }
                                                   });?>
                                                    </select>
                                                    @if ($errors->has('drugid'))
                                                        <span class="help-block">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('drugid') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                           @endif

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div  class="form-group {{ $errors->has('current_sp') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price <span class="highlight-text"> *</span>: </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input readonly type="text" id="price" name="price[]" value="" class="form-control price"/>

                                     @if ($errors->has('current_sp'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('current_sp') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

The Ajax and Jquery calls

```
 $('#div').on('#drugid','change',function(){

    var classes = $(this).parent().closest('div').attr('class').split(' '); 
    var $div = $(this).parent().attr('class');
     var id = $(this).closest('div').find('.drugid').val();
     var dataId={'id':id};

    $.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : '{!!URL::route('findPrice')!!}',
        dataType: 'json',
        data    : dataId,
        success:function(data){
        //check promotion
        var varDate = new Date(data.promo_endate); //dd-mm-YYYY
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if(data.promo_status == 'Active' && varDate >= today){

            alert($(this).parents('.form-group').parent('div').find('.price').val());
        } 
        else{

             alert($(this).parents('.form-group').parent('div').find('.price').val(current_sp));

        }
       }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such element with id as div (id="div"). But you are trying to select an element has `id="div"` using `$("#div")`

Since you want to listen to `change` of `#drugid`
Try this code :

```
$("#drugid").change(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Hope this helps you. :) Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for identifying that out... i made those changes but still no effect.